# Error in Java: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in comp sci and to java. I'm trying to do to a basic coding but when I put my code into Java it keeps saying cannot find symbol. I've tried so many different ways to fix it but I can't seem to figure out why.

The code that I put in is:

```
 public class HeightConverter{  
   public static void main (String[] args) {
    Student myName = new Student ("Rachel");
    int myAge; //age in years
    myAge = 18;
    int myHeight; //height in inches
    myHeight = 66;
    double myHeightCM; //height in cm
    myHeightCM = (2.54 * myHeight);
    System.out.println(myName.getName());
    System.out.println(myAge.getAge());
    System.out.println(myHeight.getHeight());
    System.out.println(myHeightCM.getHeight());
   }
  }
```

The response I keep getting is:

```
    Student myName = new Student ("Rachel");
    ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class HeightConverter
```

I'm sure that there are some other things in my code that's wrong too right now, but this is bugging me the most right now. Can someone explain this to me please? Thanks so much.

Comment: If that Student class is defined in another file, you have to `import` that class, e.g. `import package.holding.Student;`

Comment: where is your class `Student` ?

You may need to use `String` if you want to store your name only

Comment: Also primitives don't have getters and setters (Or any other methods) in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `Student` class defined somewhere with a constructor that takes a String and a getter method called getName()

```
class Student {
  String name ;

  public Student(String name){
    this.name = name ;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Also you need to just print your primitives directly so your code could be :

```
public class HeightConverter{  
   public static void main (String[] args) {
    Student myName = new Student ("Rachel");
    int myAge; //age in years
    myAge = 18;
    int myHeight; //height in inches
    myHeight = 66;
    double myHeightCM; //height in cm
    myHeightCM = (2.54 * myHeight);
    System.out.println(myName.getName());
    System.out.println(myAge);
    System.out.println(myHeight);
    System.out.println(myHeightCM);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Just mark the most beneficial answer as correct answer , whether this or @Predrag Maric 's one to mark the question as answered ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have class named `Student`, and that class has to be imported, unless it is located in the same package as the `HeightConverter` class.

```
import com.some.package.Student;
```

And that's just the first error, there are more. You should first find some basic Java tutorial, and also read what the IDE tells you. In every IDE you will get a warning/error message about what's wrong with your code. If you don't use one - use it.